# Copy horizontal data vertically in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

This is first time I got stuck after taking all help from this site for last 5 years. This is my first question so might not be to the point, however, I will try my best. My source data is something like in image Snip1, where Column A, B and C are merged and contains some values, from Column D to K it have corresponding values of the month.

Snip1
[image: Snip1]

The output will be as given in Snip2 where the value of column A,B and C remains the same, then in D will be the corresponding month where there is some value and then Column E will have that value. If there is a value in another month then in row 2 it will put the same value of Column A,B and C and the corresponding Month where there is value followed by the value in column E.

Snip2
[image: Snip2]

This will continue till the last filled cell of Column A, B and C. Is this possible with Macro?

```
Sub Example()
```

Dim myRow As Long
Dim rowPointer As Long
Dim columnPointer As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim LastRowIndex As Long

myRow = 1

LastRowIndex = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

```
For rowPointer = 2 To LastRowIndex
    lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For columnPointer = 2 To lastColumn
    Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, 1).Value
    Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, columnPointer).Value
    myRow = myRow + 1
Next columnPointer
Next rowPointer
```

End Sub

Comment: yes it is possible.Try and code something and share where you are stuck. It looks like an unpivot on the end columns (months) then removal of blanks rows (within those unpivoted columns). You could likely use powerquery for this.

Comment: Thanks, as powerquery is not an option I can try, I used this:Dim myRow As Long
Dim rowPointer, columnPointer,lastColumn,LastRowIndex As Long
myRow = 1
LastRowIndex = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For rowPointer = 2 To LastRowIndex
lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For columnPointer = 2 To lastColumn
Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, 1).Value
Sheet2.Cells(myRow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowPointer, columnPointer).Value
myRow = myRow + 1
Next columnPointer
Next rowPointer This did not helped

Comment: hi, use the [edit] link to insert your code between code tags in your question.